# C# Linq search list within list

Tags: c#, linq

I am writing a domino draw game in C# and would like to know if there is a simpler/better way to know the player that has been dealt the highest double bone (where x equals y) and what bone it is:

```
public class Player
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Bone> Bones;
    public Player(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

public class Bone 
{
    public int x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }
}
```

Code in question (players is a list of player):

```
//select player with highest double and select the double
var pdb = players.SelectMany(pl => pl.Bones.Where(b => b.x == b.y)
    .Select(b => new { player = pl, doublebones = b }))
    .OrderByDescending(db => db.doublebones.x)
    .First();
Player playerWithHighestDouble = pdb.player;
Bone highestBone = pdb.doublebones;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to CodeReview.  What you are trying to do is simple enough that your LINQ implementation is okay.  Let's face it, with dominoes you are not going to have a million players with a million bones, so no need to worry about performance issues with a fairly small set.

You didn't ask explicitly for review of other parts of code, but I will offer them anyway.

`Name` could be a read-only property set only in the constructor.

You have `Bones` as a field, not a property.  It could be exposed as a public `IReadOnlyList`, and it probably should be a property.

`Bone` could be a `struct` or a `class` since it only has 2 `int` properties.  I do not like the names `X` and `Y` as I tend to think of Cartesian coordinates and therefore a location.  I would prefer to see names like `Square1` and `Square2`.  I would probably keep this as a `class` and make the properties readonly as well.  You may consider adding extra properties such as `IsDouble`, and even override `ToString()` with `$"{Square1}-{Square2}"`, and maybe even `Pips` which is a sum of both squares.

As you are new to CR, since I have posted an answer, do NOT alter your code in your question or else a moderator will roll it back.

Comment: thanks a lot for the review, your suggestions make sense.